# How to securely erase an NVMe SSD

Tags: ssd, disk-encryption, nvme, secure-erase, cryptographic-erase

It's generally accepted that SSDs cannot be securely wiped by writing patterns to the drive, due to features such as wear leveling and over-provisioning, and that the most secure way to wipe a modern SSD is using the ATA Secure Erase firmware commands.

However, from my understanding this doesn't seem to apply to NVMe drives because they're not ATA-based - instead, they connect via the PCIe bus. Looking at the [Parted Magic tool](https://partedmagic.com/nvme-secure-erase/) seems to confirm that NVMe drives have their own equivalent to the ATA Secure Erase command for SATA SSDs:

[image]

However, I haven't been able to find an NVMe equivalent for `hdparm`. How exactly can I securely erase an NVMe SSD? I'm running Windows, but also have access to a Unix-like environment using Cygwin.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310338/how-to-secure-erase-a-nvme-ssd

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's true that `hdparm` will not work for NVMe drives, because they don't use the traditional ATA interface protocol that SATA drives use to send low-level firmware commands to the drive.

Thankfully, there's an open-source tool that allows sending the equivalent commands to NMVe drives - [`nvme-cli`](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli). The tool has already been made available as a package for many distributions, and can be compiled for many more.

Once you have the tool installed with something like:

```
apt-get install nvme-cli
```

You can then list all recognised NVMe devices with:

```
nvme list
```

To [securely erase](http://blog.pythonaro.com/2018/05/how-to-securely-wipe-nvme-drive.html) a listed NVMe SSD, run:

```
nvme format -s1 /dev/nvme0n1
```

...where `/dev/nvme0n1` is the block name of the listed device.

Comment: To securely erase all data of a NVMe hard drive on any computer, a bootable grml Linux USB stick is suitable. It contains `nvme-cli` out of the box.

Comment: I like `nvme format -s2 /dev/nvmeXnY` to erase the encryption key.  Then follow up with a `blkdiscard /dev/nvmeXnY` to make sure everything is trim and zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `nvme-cli` one can do ["PSID revert"](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/PSID-Revert) using `sedutil`. Some vendor-specific software also provide this function (e.g. "Secure Erase" in [Samsung Magician](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/us/consumer-storage/magician/)).